# Real IP address + port from cloudflare over nginx proxy manager to apache

Tags: apache, nginx, ip, port, cloudflare

I'm looking for a way to "pipe" the clients real IP address and port from Cloudflare over NGINX Proxy Manager to the main webserver apache.

The system is implemented in docker. The domain is configurated by cloudflare with proxy. I got a docker container with nginx that pipe the users requests to the apache container.

I want to log the original, real IP addresses AND the ports of users. I don't care where I pick up the data, whether it's from NGINX or Apache or, if necessary, from cloudflare. Preferably with the apache.

In PHP you get with:

- $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] -> the IP address of the NGINX container (sure)
- $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] -> the real IP address of the user (what I want)

I don't know whether the original port is behind $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']. Probably not.
With Cloudflare there is the possibility to define additional fields in which the port could be passed through. How do I get to the field / the port.

Thanks a lot and best greetings
Mtz

A wasy to pipe the users original IP addresses and ports through Cloudflare and NGINX to apache (to log them).

Answer (score 0):

I think in Nginx Proxy Manager, select the proxy host of your Apache web server and under the Advanced tab you can add this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_cf_connecting_ip;
```